# Sending pct (%) in query param in rest API

Tags: java, spring, rest

I am having a rest API where end point is like this:

```
/private/items/query
```

where I am taking id as query param so url is like:

```
http://localhost:8081/private/items/query?id=item1234
```

Now when the item contains `%` symbol its not reaching as query param in my APIs properly e.g. in case of `item%21` what I am receiving is `item!`.

How can this problem be fixed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `%` symbol is generally used to encode special characters in query string e.g. `+` is encoded to `%2B` while sending as query string.

As mentioned [here][1]:

> Because the percent ("%") character serves as the indicator for
> percent-encoded octets, it must be percent-encoded as "%25" for that
> octet to be used as data within a URI.

In your case you need to send `%2521` which will be decoded to `%21` at the backend as `%25` is `%` when url-decoded. You can use this [link][2] for url-encoding purpose.
[1]: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2.4
[2]: https://www.urlencoder.org/